Почему не подключается зависимость в Maven проекте?
Я создал Maven-проект, добавил зависимость в pom.xml, но в main я не могу использовать никакие классы из данной библиотеки, т.к. idea просто не видит их. Объясните полному нубу, что происходит?



Наверное не синхронизирован pom.xml  после добавления зависимости. На последнем скрине есть маленькая иконка в правом углу с буквой m. Для синхронизации внесенных изменений в pom.xml можно нажать на неё. Либо в idea нажать Alt + F12 и ввести команду mvn dependency:resolve для загрузки зависимости.
Затем добавить импорт классов в Main.
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;

Иногда может глючить сама Idea. В этом случае может помочь очистка кэша IDE.
File -> Invalidate Caches ... -> поставить все галки и нажать Ок.

Программа не знает, что такое github, как с этим жить?

@Hrats_ нужно больше подробностей. Что значит не знает? Сама зависимость будет скачиваться отсюда: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.docker-java/docker-java . Из репозитория maven central. GitHub ей не нужен.

import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient. Пишет cannot resolve symbol 'github'

@Hrats_ возможно глючит idea. Может помочь File->Invalidate Caches ...  -> поставить все галки и нажать Ок. Если это не поможет, то попробуйте взять за основу этот проект: https://github.com/Falchio/docker-java. Создал минимальный проект, с одной зависимостью и кодом со скрина. В нём не было проблем с импортом зависимости.

Спасибо, вроде начало работать

@Hrats_ а что в итоге помогло? Очистка кэша?
